# Android - Running background application is not visible in the task manager

Tags: android, taskmanager, background-application

I developed a music player with service to handle playing music. When I run the music player in background I can't see it in task manager. How can I make the background running application visible in task manager? Thanks~

Comment: I have a notification for the music player when it running background. My problem is I want it visible in task manager when it running background

Answer (score 1):

All running services are shown on the running services list under applications. I seriously hope you CAN NOT hide them.

Icons do not need to appear on the main application menu. You can remove the icon from appearing on this menu by not defining an icon/label in your manifest.

Your request sounds sketchy/shady.

Answer (score 0):

Most music player apps put an ongoing notification in the notification panel. You can have it so that when the user taps on the notification, it opens your music player so they can stop it.

With the new notification APIs in JellyBean, you could have a notification with buttons on it so they can control it without opening the app also.

Read up on them here: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html